# Chromedriver Keeps Changing Timezone When Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Below is the beginning of my Python code that successfully scrapes all the table information from this [website](https://www.oddsportal.com/baseball/usa/mlb-2018/results/) and exports it to a CSV file. The only issue I'm having with this scraper is Chromedriver keeps changing the timezone in the top right-hand corner which ultimately distorts my output by assigning some games with the incorrect date. I've tried looking in the page source for links or tags that will allow me to click "GMT-8 Pacific Time Zone", but unfortunately I cannot find anything. The frustrating part is when I copy and paste the URL into my browser, Chrome immediately switches back to Pacific time zone. Does anyone know how to fix this timezone issue when using Chromedriver to scrape data? Thanks in advance!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import re
import pandas as pd

# set scope and create empty lists
year = 2018
lastpage = 50
Date = []
Time = []
Team1 = []
Team2 = []
Score = []
All_ML = []
Team1_ML = []
Team2_ML = []

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.oddsportal.com/')
driver.execute_script('op.selectTimeZone(6);')

# set up for loop to loop through all pages
for x in range(1, lastpage + 1):
    url = "http://www.oddsportal.com/baseball/usa/mlb-" + str(year) + "/results/#/page/" + str(x) + "/'"
    driver.get(url)


    # wait until java table loads and then grab data
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tournamentTable"]')))
    odds = element.text
    print (odds)

    # close temporary chrome screen
    driver.close()

    # reformat resulting text for consistency
    odds = re.sub("[0-9] - ", str(year)[-1] + " -- ", odds)
    odds = re.sub(" - ", "\nteam2", odds)

    # split text by line
    odds = odds.split("\n")

    counter = 1

    # set up loop to classify each line of text
    for line in odds:

        # if a game was abandoned or cancelled, set score to N/A
        if re.match(".*( {1})[a-zA-Z]*\.$", line):
            Score.append("N/A")

            # if date format is matched, add to date list and reset counter
        if re.match("(.{2} .{3} .{4}.*)", line):
            currdate = line[:11]
            Date.append(currdate)
            counter = 1

        # if time format is matched at beginning of string, add time to list, add team1 to list, check if there was a new date for this game. if not, add current date from previous game
        elif re.match('(.{2}:.{2})', line):
            Time.append(line[:5])
            Team1.append(line[6:])
            if counter > 1:
                Date.append(currdate)
            counter += 1

        # if its a team2 line, add to team2 list. if score is on the same line, add to score list
        elif re.match("team2.*", line):
            if re.match(".*:.*", line):
                Score.append(re.sub("[a-zA-Z]* *", "", line[-5:]))
                Team2.append(re.sub(" {1}[0-9]*:[0-9]*", "", line[5:len(line)]))
            else:
                Team2.append(re.sub(" {1}[a-zA-Z]*\.", "", line[5:]))

        # if score is on it's own line, add to score list
        elif re.match(".*:.*", line):
            Score.append(re.sub(" ", "", line))

        # add all moneylines to a list
        elif re.match("[+\-.*]", line):
            All_ML.append(line)

    # add odd money lines to list1, even moneylines to list 2
    Team1_ML = All_ML[0::2]
    Team2_ML = All_ML[1::2]

# create dataframe with all lists
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Date': Date,
     'Time': Time,
     'Team1': Team1,
     'Team2': Team2,
     'Score': Score,
     'Team1_ML': Team1_ML,
     'Team2_ML': Team2_ML})

# save
df.to_csv('odds2018.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To flesh out pguardiario's note, if you use Chrome devtools to look at the button in the top right, each of the buttons trigger a link to `https://www.oddsportal.com/set-timezone/n/` where `n` is some timezone code. Those functions actually actually trigger a function `op.selectTimeZone(n)`, that will change your timezone on screen. You can experiment with this in your Chrome console by typing `op.selectTimeZone(n)`.

If this works for you, you can incorporate this by emulating console javascript calls using, where `n` is the code for the selected timezone:

```
driver.execute_script('op.selectTimeZone(n);')
```

You can add that after every driver initialization call, to force set the time zone, e.g:

```
for x in range(1, lastpage + 1):
    url = "http://www.oddsportal.com/baseball/usa/mlb-" + str(year) + "/results/#/page/" + str(x) + "/'"

   driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)

    # Set timezone
    driver.execute_script('op.selectTimeZone(6);')

    # wait until java table loads and then grab data
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tournamentTable"]')))
    odds = element.text
```

Note that you may need to play with setting the wait timer, as you are adding extra execution after the select time zone.

Also, there really is no need for you to reset the driver call for every loop, unless you are planning to parallelize the `for` loop. This will likely run much faster if you take the driver initialization and closing out of the loop.

**EDIT:**

So it seems that, if you access the results page directly, you will not be able to set the timezone without triggering a reload on the page. You likely would need to take the setting and loading out of the loop, e.g.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.oddsportal.com/')
# Proc JS on-click for timezone selection button
driver.execute_script("op.showHideTimeZone();ElementSelect.expand( 'user-header-timezone' , 'user-header-timezone-expander' , null , function(){op.hideTimeZone()} );this.blur();")
driver.execute_script('op.selectTimeZone(6);')

for x in range(1, lastpage + 1):
    url = "http://www.oddsportal.com/baseball/usa/mlb-" + str(year) + "/results/#/page/" + str(x) + "/'"

    driver.get(url)

    # wait until java table loads and then grab data
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tournamentTable"]')))
    odds = element.text
    print(odds)
# close temporary chrome screen
driver.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, Mike! Very informative. I have added the driver.execute_script line, but I keep getting this error..`selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined`. Would you happen to know why this is happening? I've tried playing around with the wait timer but that doesn't seem to be the issue here. Thanks again!

Comment: I've taken a look at the website, and it's to do with how the webpage loads timezone selections. If you try to change your timezone on the paginated results page, as you are doing now, it will fail. You need to take the driver initialization out of the loop, go to the home page, then loop through the results page, then finally closing the driver.

Comment: Thank you, Mike! Unfortunately, I am now getting a different error... `selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property '6' of undefined` Any idea why the code will not recognize the 6? I've updated my question so you can see the entire code I wrote for this scraper. Thanks again for the feedback!

Comment: The error comes from within the function `op.selectTimeZone`, where some variables are not being initialized. It seems to work if you proc the timezone selection button (class `user-header-fakeselect`), or the attached JS on-click function as I've done in the edited code.

Comment: Thank you, Mike. This has been very helpful. Last question, I promised. When I run your edited code, the Chrome browser opens, changes the time zone, then immediately shuts and I get this error... `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid session id`. I've researched other posts with this error and most people say it is because Chromedriver is not up to date, but I'm using the latest version so that shouldn't be the issue. The weird part is the output gets printed, but the code is unable to go through the loop. Thoughts? Thanks again!

Comment: There might be other issues, but the immediate error I see is that your `driver.close()` is nested in your loop, and therefore it closes your browser after your first loop. When your second loop starts it will try to access the same Chrome instance via ID, that has already been closed, and therefore throw the error. If there are no particular reason that you close your Chrome instance after every run, you should leave that at the end, before `# create dataframe with all lists`.

Comment: To elaborate a tiny bit, if you call `.close()` while you have more than 1 window open for the specific chrome instance, it will only close the window in focus. If you only have one window, it will kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can set that with:

```
driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/set-timezone/6/")
```

Comment: Thanks, pguardiario! Would you mind clarifying how to incorporate the link you mentioned into the loop? Right now when I use your link, it sends me to the website's home page, and not the baseball page I am trying to scrape.